# Cloud Dataflow job is not getting listed in Cloud Dataflow Console Dashboard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I tried to execute my python dataflow code with below command line argument.

python upload_simple_csv.py --runner DataflowRunner --project bigquery-poc-188207  --save_main_session True --temp_location gs://resources-poc-atul/temp --num_workers 1

https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow

But at the same time, when I am submitting other dataflow job its getting listed. eg: python spikey_top_selling_products.py --input gs://resources-poc-atul/data/spikey_sales_we
ekly.csv  --output gs://resources-poc-atul/output/ --runner DataflowRunner --project bigquery-poc-188207 --temp_location gs://resources-poc-atul/temp/ --num_workers=4 --save_main_session TR
UE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any ongoing issues but I suggest contacting [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) if the issue persists.

Comment: Mistakenly I had removed dataflow part from my code. Now once I have added that part.it's working fine.